# Set TextBox value with js injection in a WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, javascript-injection

Using Android Studio I am trying to set the value of a textbox in a login form of a web page which is not mine.

Here's the webView i use to work on the page:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('j_password').value = 'something'");
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://sg18224.scuolanext.info/");
```

the problem is that when the page has finished loading instead of setting the textbox value, the whole page becomes white and it only displays the string i was trying to  set as value (in this case "something").
If i include the js line in an alert like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: alert(document.getElementById('j_password').value = 'something')");
```

it works! But also displays an alert i don't want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
final String js = "javascript:document.getElementById('j_password').value='something';";
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String s) { }
            });
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(js);
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with this answer but you may try it. typically it should be the answer. Long time no interaction with javascript though.

you may try

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('j_password').innerHTML = 'something'");
```

please comment if its not working.

Comment: It's not working because the TextBox in HTML is like
`<input name="j_password" id="j_password" type="password" class="input password" value="Password">`
And has no innerHTML